# Real time notification system on Google App Engine(GAE)

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

How to implement facebook like real time notification system on Google App Engine(GAE)? Basically my site contains articles on various topics. Users can comment on them. So now I need to notify all online users who commented on the article about newly added comment with a notification.

UPDATE:

channel API quota allows only 100 channels per day for an application and also only 6 channels/min rate limit when using without billing enabled. I'm shocked with these limitations. Also when billing is enabled only 60 channels/min can be created. I don't think its possible to implement with these limitations.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the channel api is your friend.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview

EDIT:
use an external messaging service like http://pusher.com if the quota limits do not fit your needs.

Comment: channel API quota allows only 100 channels per day for an application and also only 6 channels/min rate limit when using without billing enabled. I'm shocked with these limitations. I don't think its possible to implement with these limitations. Also when billing is enabled only 60 channels/min can be created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Channel API:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview?hl=en

if you r using the GWT, it will be very easy!
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-channel/wiki/HowToUse